# Error MSB6006 "icl.exe" exited with code 4. while building a project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently porting a huge (at least for me! ;-)) solution to MSVS2012. About half the projects use Intel C++ compiler 13 (icl.exe).

Sometime, when I resume a build (after it stopped due to errors) I get the following error:

**Error MSB6006: "icl.exe" exited with code 4.**

What does it mean? Usually, I need to clean the faulty project then rebuild it to make this error vanish.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Notice that is _doesn't_ seem to be a fatal error because a clean usualy makes the log disappear. It is **annoying**.

Comment: This usually means "too many open files".  Some hits on Intel forums but they are all dead since Intel changed their login procedure.  That's where you should ask.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i went to the "Output" tab in VS and the real error indication was there (in my case: "Catastrophic error: cannot open source file "path\file.c").
**"icl.exe" exited with code 4** links to some compiler configuration file but the real problem was not really there